# 'Method not found: !!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map<!0>(object)' (ASP.NET Zero)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

In ASP.NET Zero, in Xamarin.Forms, I have started receiving this error out of essentially nowhere:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  Message=Method not found: !!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map<!0>(object)
```

Does anyone know the fix for the same?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of AutoMapper do you have in your .csproj file?

Comment: Found the solution to the error. It had to do with the AutoMapper being added to projects it shouldn't have been added to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have added the AutoMapper to the right projects. If it has been added to projects apart from where it is required, there are high chances of you receiving this error.